# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Windows Phone Stack Exchange](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is Windows Phone equivalent to Google Nexus series?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/what-is-windows-phone-equivalent-to-google-nexus-series)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to install Windows 10 Technical Preview for phones?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8792/how-to-install-windows-10-technical-preview-for-phones)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Will current WP7.x & WP8.x apps continue to work with Windows 10 for phones?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8726/will-current-wp7-x-wp8-x-apps-continue-to-work-with-windows-10-for-phones)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What Does "Update Apps Automatically" Mean?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8716/what-does-update-apps-automatically-mean)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Can I download, re-sign, and distribute a Windows Store app across an organisation?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8890/can-i-download-re-sign-and-distribute-a-windows-store-app-across-an-organisati)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Where do my sound recordings get stored and how can I get them off my phone?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8933/where-do-my-sound-recordings-get-stored-and-how-can-i-get-them-off-my-phone)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [SD card photos aren't displayed when attaching photos in WhatsApp/Hike](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8839/sd-card-photos-arent-displayed-when-attaching-photos-in-whatsapp-hike)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Ativ S doesn't go in download mode](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8941/ativ-s-doesnt-go-in-download-mode)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Nokia Lumia 520 freezes on boot](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8751/nokia-lumia-520-freezes-on-boot)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [How can I delete Other files in storage?](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/8806/how-can-i-delete-other-files-in-storage)

**Net Score: -7** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 7)

---